# Python Polars: Calculate rolling mode over multiple columns

Tags: python, python-polars, rolling-computation

I have a `polars.DataFrame` like:

```
data = pl.DataFrame({
"col1": [3, 2, 4, 7, 1, 10, 7],
"col2": [3, 4, None, 1, None, 1, 9],
"col3": [3, 1, None, None, None, None, 4],
"col4": [None, 5, None, None, None, None, None],
"col5": [None, None, None, None, None, None, None]})

┌──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ col1 ┆ col2 ┆ col3 ┆ col4 ┆ col5 │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ f32  │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 3    ┆ 3    ┆ 3    ┆ null ┆ null │
│ 2    ┆ 4    ┆ 1    ┆ 5    ┆ null │
│ 4    ┆ null ┆ null ┆ null ┆ null │
│ 7    ┆ 1    ┆ null ┆ null ┆ null │
│ 1    ┆ null ┆ null ┆ null ┆ null │
│ 10   ┆ 1    ┆ null ┆ null ┆ null │
│ 7    ┆ 9    ┆ 4    ┆ null ┆ null │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘
```

I want to create a new column that contains the rolling `mode` - but not based on one column and the respective row values within the window **but on row values of all columns** within the window. The `nulls` should be dropped and shouldn't appear in the resulting columns as a mode value.

*edit:*

I made some changes to the example data provided. For further clarifications and under the assumption of something like `polars.rolling_apply(<function>, window_size=2, min_periods=1, center=False)` I would expect the following result:

```
┌──────┐
│ res  │
│ ---  │
│ i64  │
╞══════╡
│ 3    │
│ 3    │
│ 4    │
│ None │ <- all values different
│ 1    │
│ 1    │
│ None │ <- all values different
└──────┘
```

In case there is no mode `None` as a result would be fine. Only the missing value in the original `polars.DataFrame` should be ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can use [`.group_by_rolling()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.group_by_rolling.html) to create the windows.
- [`.concat_list()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/expressions/lists/#row-wise-computations) can be used collect each row into a list
- This leaves a 2-row nested list `[[col1, col2, ...], [col1, col2, ...]]` which we can [`.flatten()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.flatten.html#polars.Expr.flatten)
- Finally, we can [`.drop_nulls()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.drop_nulls.html#polars.Expr.drop_nulls) before getting the [`.mode()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.mode.html#polars.Expr.mode)

```py
(df.with_row_count()
   .group_by_rolling(
      pl.col("row_nr").cast(int),
      period = "2i"
   )
   .agg(mode = 
      pl.concat_list(pl.exclude("row_nr")).flatten().drop_nulls().mode()
   )
#   .with_columns(
#      pl.when(pl.col("mode").list.lengths() == 1)
#        .then(pl.col("mode").list.first())
#   )
)
```

```py
shape: (7, 2)
┌────────┬────────────────────┐
│ row_nr ┆ mode               │
│ ---    ┆ ---                │
│ i64    ┆ list[f64]          │
╞════════╪════════════════════╡
│ 0      ┆ [3.0]              │
│ 1      ┆ [3.0]              │
│ 2      ┆ [4.0]              │
│ 3      ┆ [1.0, 7.0, 4.0]    │
│ 4      ┆ [1.0]              │
│ 5      ┆ [1.0]              │
│ 6      ┆ [10.0, 9.0, … 4.0] │
└────────┴────────────────────┘
```

The commented out lines ignore the tied rows and unpack the lists.

```py
shape: (7, 2)
┌────────┬──────┐
│ row_nr ┆ mode │
│ ---    ┆ ---  │
│ i64    ┆ f64  │
╞════════╪══════╡
│ 0      ┆ 3.0  │
│ 1      ┆ 3.0  │
│ 2      ┆ 4.0  │
│ 3      ┆ null │
│ 4      ┆ 1.0  │
│ 5      ┆ 1.0  │
│ 6      ┆ null │
└────────┴──────┘
```

Comment: So as I understand, your code behaves somewhat like an **expanding window** like *rolling_mean(window_size=df.height)*?

Comment: Yes indeed - it seems I may have misinterpreted the question.

Comment: The new version seems to work out! Somehow I had to use *.groupby_rolling()* instead of the alias *.group_by_rolling()*.

Comment: Yeah, the underscore in `_by` was introduced in `v0.19.0` - if you update you should get a deprecation warning for the old name.